# How to enumerate child VMs of a particular component type in VueJS?

Tags: vue.js

VueJS [$children](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#vm-children) provides an array of all Vue components.

I want to iterate through only a particular type of component, but I can't find a way to get each child's "name" out of the object!

e.g.

```
export default {                                                                                         
  name: 'mainapp',
  components: { Component1, Component2 },
  methods: {
    doSomething() {
      for (c of this.$children) {
        if (c IS Component1) ... // ← how to do this?
      }
    }
  }
}
```

And component1 might include

```
export default {
  name: 'Component1',
  // ...
}
```

Comment: You can access each child's name as such `this.$children[n].$options.name` or `this.$children[n].constructor.options.name`, but that would leave it up to you to make sure that the names were distinct.

Comment: @StevenB. Thanks! that's the answer!